# Grammar: goes or went

Tags: grammar

In Book [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf):

> I think, therefore I am. However, with just a few more lines of argument in this vein, [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) **goes** on to conclude that there is an infinitely beneficent God.

It says that `Descartes goes ...`. Shouldn't it be `Descartes went`?
Is this a grammar error or some kind of special usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **storytelling**, the present tense can be used instead of past. 
Stories are often told in the present tenses. 
Example: 
Jack goes to Joe's house. Jack asks for a drink and gives Joe some cake. 
Your example seems to be a story being told, rather than a past event. Therefore, using "goes" should be correct.

If you're talking about actual past events, however, you should use past tenses instead.